# SSRS Report Designer and SharePoint 2010 Mixed-mode Authentication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

We have a SharePoint 2010 installation that connects to a SQL Server 2008 R2 reporting server which is running in SharePoint Integrated Mode.

Initially, our web application was using Classic Mode authentication, and Report Builder passed through our Windows credentials as expected. Some time later, we switched to Claims Based Authentication, with only the Windows Authentication type enabled. Report Builder was still logging in automatically as expected.

Yesterday, we enabled Forms Based Authentication alongside the existing Windows Auth (we also deployed a custom login page - not sure if this is relevant?). Report Builder is now prompting for credentials when we attempt to connect to the report server. Even worse, it will only accept Forms Based Authentication accounts - entering my Windows credentials does not work.

How can we get Report Builder to pass through our Windows credentials as it did previously? If that's not possible, can we at least get it to accept Windows credentials as well?

Comment: When you say "we enabled Forms Based Authentication alongside the existing Windows Auth", did you extend the web app into a new IIS site and SharePoint zone? Just looking for some more details.